# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Show Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got a simple search form, in rails 4 app, that needs two params passed to be able to show relevant data.

I'm getting an 'Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'data inputted' but the columns do exist. If I instead of '`@search = Page.where(params[:one] && params[:two])`' use '`@search = Page.all`' the data shows, but all of it shows.

**Form**

```
<%= form_tag(page_show_path, id: "search-form") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :one, params[:one], placeholder: "One" %>
  <%= text_field_tag :two, params[:two], placeholder: "Two" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

**Model**

```
  def self.one(query)
    where("one = ?", "%#{query}%") 
  end
  def self.two(query)
    where("two = ?", "%#{query}%") 
  end
```

**Controller**

```
def show

    if (params[:one] && params[:two]).present?
     @search = Page.where(params[:one] && params[:two])
    else
     redirect_to page_path, notice: "Not a valid combination"
    end
  end
```

Comment: what are your column names?

Comment: try to change 'one' with 'One'. May be this issue is of case sensitivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Create and Use Scope.

```
scope :find_one_two, ->(query_one, query_two) { where("one  = ? AND two = ? ",  query_one, query_two) }

@search = Page.find_one_two(params[:one], params[:two])
```

**OR**

You can use.

```
@search = Page.where("one = ? AND two = ?", params[:one], params[:two])
```

Comment: This got it, used the second option. I swear I tried that though... haha. Beer time!

Answer (score 0):

```
def show
  if (params[:one] && params[:two]).present?
   @search = Page.where("one like ? AND two like ? ", "%#{params[:one]}%", "%#{params[:two]}%")
  else
   redirect_to page_path, notice: "Not a valid combination"
  end
end
```

This may solve your problem.